# When build it breaks the block I just built in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I am playing skywars or bedwars and I try to build a bridge it starts to break the block I'm standing on,which makes me fall. This normally happens when I try to ninja bridge.

(Ninja bridge is when you hit shift and shift again to make yourself go faster when building a bridge)

For Reference: I'm using a Logitech M325C

Comment: That's just lag.

Answer (score 1):

## You are lagging

The only way of a block to disappear in minecraft is due to a restriction (imposed by command blocks or server side) or lag.

For checking it: go to a local singleplayer world and build a bridge, check if blocks disappear. 
**Spoiler:** you will never fall.